# Gaussian elimination: all variables in row are zero but constant is non-zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, self-learning, gaussian-elimination

I'm starting linear algebra next week and been trying to get a little ahead. I'm working with a practice sheet I found through Google. One of the problems has the equations

$2x+5y=9$

$x+2y-z=3$

$-3x-4y+7z=1$

I'm putting this system in reduced echelon form, I've tried several different elimination paths but I keep getting the same result which is that the bottom row ends up as

0 0 0 | 4

I can get the system to ref but I'm not sure how to treat this row, all variables have a zero coefficient but there's a non-zero constant.

Do I just ignore that row since it doesn't help me solve the system? Or does it help me solve the system in some way I don't know about yet? Or am I doing my row operations wrong somehow?

I start with the augmented matrix

2 5 0 | 9

1 2 -1 | 3

-3 -4 7 | 1

I do operations

$-R_2+R_1->R_1$

$-R_1+R_2->R_2$

$3R_1+R_3->R_3$

$5R_2+R_3->R_3$

And I end up with the matrix

1 3 1 | 6

0 -1 -2 | -3

0 0 0 | 4

Any help or explanation will be appreciated!

(I'm trying to learn the formatting, thanks for your patience)

Comment: A zero row followed by a nonzero constant indiciates that there cannot be a solution since this row is a clear contradiction.

Comment: A zero row followed by a zero can be ignored. This usually means that there are infinite many solutions , unless a contradiction occurs later.